# carrierwave exception for upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave to upload image files. I basically have a form field "_form.html.erb" that has a title, description, image and category that is submitted to the DB. What I want to do is if a category is != to "social" then check for image presence but if it is equal to social then go ahead and submit to DB without an image. Right now I get a error when submitting "Image can't be blank". I thought this error might be coming from the validates_presence_of :image line that I have in my model but not sure about this. So I tried to wrap it in a if statement block, but I'm still getting it. Does anyone know how I get around what I'm trying to do.

```
if :category != "social" 
    validates_presence_of :image
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Proc`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html) with the `:if` option on the validator.

```
validates :image, presence: true, if: Proc.new { |a| a.category != "social" }
```

Recommended Reading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#using-a-proc-with-if-and-unless

Comment: I still don't understand from your link why using a Proc would make this work. A Proc is just an object of saved code. This worked for me and thanks for the code.

Comment: Well first of all, `if :category != "social"` will never work regardless of context. The Symbol `:category` converted to a String will *ever* equal the String `"social"`. The `Proc` works because Rails supports it through the `:if` or `:unless` options. It will pass the current model's context to the `Proc` *(That's what `a` is inside the `Proc`)*. That `Proc`'s return value is used to evaluate the `:if` or `:unless` to conditionally apply the validator.